# Showing only Youtube channel video's thumbnail in WebView in Android

Tags: java, android, webview

As you may know for my recent questions here, I'm new to Android developing.

Sorry if the question sounds too general, but the problem that I'm having is that I don't know how to show just the videos from one Youtube channel (the thumbnails) and not the whole webpage. What I do is:

`WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
 myWebView.loadUrl("https://youtube.com/users/onechannel");
 myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

So as I mention, the result is obviously like if I oppened that URL on my web browser (pretty logical watching the code I wrote). Anyway, I just want to show the videos' thumbnails so you can scroll up and down and see just the videos, and not any kind of header from that Youtube channel. Is that even possible?

My problem is that I'm obviously not so much into WebViews so any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a WebView so you're just embedding the youtube channel webpage into a view.

I don't think there's much you can customize from the rendered page it self since it all depends on what webpage has contained it self, so the div elements and such that are being send over from the server. You could do some hacking and make it appear differently but that wouldn't be the right way around.

I'd suggest you to use the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels) and create a custom View and manually populate the thumbnails your self with it. It is way more work then you've probably expected but that's probably the best solution that I know of.

It's worth mentioning that I've done some android development on a intermediate level but I'm not a expert so somebody else out there might be able to help you out even more.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'll definetely check the Youtube API. It was actually what I thought I was going to end up doing, anyway I just wanted to know if there were some kind of black magic methods doing what I needed. When you get started you never know haha

Comment: You'd have to ask a more experienced android developer that I'm afraid. I haven't developed android apps long enough to know what libraries are available to make this easier however after some quick googling I did manage to find this https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git%2Fandroid-player%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fexamples%2Fyoutubeapidemo

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will check it!